# Is it possible to use a component property as a data variable?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I've copied my current code below.  I'm trying to dynamically generate table headers depending on what `type` I pass as a prop to my `tables` component (standings and status are what I have as the data arrays in my example).

I've accomplished this by using the `if` statement in the `header` computed value to return the proper list.

However I'd like to not have to add additional `if` statements for every `type`.

Is there a way that I can leverage the `type` prop to bind directly to the matching data?

```
<div id="root" class="container">
    <tables type="stats">

    </tables>
</div>

Vue.component('tables', {
  template: `
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="headers in header">{{ headers }}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="footers in header">{{ footers }}</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leicester_City_F.C." title="Leicester City F.C.">Leicester City</a> <strong>(C)</strong>
        <slot></slot>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  `,

  data () {
    return {
      standings: ['Rank', 'Team', 'Wins', 'Losses'],
      stats: ['Number', 'Player', 'Position', 'RBI', 'HR']
    };
  },

  computed: {
    header() {
      if (this.type == 'standings') {
        return this.standings;
      } else {
        return this.stats;
      }
    }
  },

  props: {
    type: { required: true }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change up your data structure slightly, you can remove your if statements.

```
  data () {
    return {
      types:{
        standings: ['Rank', 'Team', 'Wins', 'Losses'],
        stats: ['Number', 'Player', 'Position', 'RBI', 'HR']
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    header() {
      return this.types[this.type]
    }
  },
  props: {
    type: { required: true }
  }
```

Here is an example.

```js
Vue.component('tables', {
  template: `
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="headers in header">{{ headers }}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="footers in header">{{ footers }}</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>1</th>
        <td><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leicester_City_F.C." title="Leicester City F.C.">Leicester City</a> <strong>(C)</strong>
        <slot></slot>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  `,

  data () {
    return {
      types:{
        standings: ['Rank', 'Team', 'Wins', 'Losses'],
        stats: ['Number', 'Player', 'Position', 'RBI', 'HR']
      }
    };
  },
  computed: {
    header() {
      return this.types[this.type]
    }
  },
  props: {
    type: { required: true }
  }

});

new Vue({
 el: "#root"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root" class="container">
    <tables type="stats">

    </tables>
</div>
```

Comment: It's funny, like no more than 5 minutes ago I had almost the exact same idea as you, but I didn't realize you could qualify a list of arrays like that in your data () section. Mine looked a little more like what I pasted below and was still having issues with it.

Your solution is perfect.  I'm still learning JS and Vue and this actually just vaulted me past a roadblock, thanks so much!

`      headerFormats: [
        {headerType: 'standings', header: ['Rank', 'Team', 'Wins', 'Losses']},
        {headerType: 'stats', header: ['Number', 'Player', 'Position', 'RBI', 'HR']}
      ]`

Comment: @JimDaily You're welcome :) It's not really *qualifying* anything, it's just setting a data property as an object and using it like a dictionary. You could use an array like you are doing there in your comment too, it would just be a little slower.